# Android reading png from application folder / do i need to move them?

Tags: android, image, loading, bundle, assets

I have some 150+ PNG in my application that I need to constantly read.

Do i have to move these files from my assets folder to /data/data/myApp.com/ as I do for opening a database?

OR

isn't there a way, as in iPhone, to just read from the application bundle?

As if, instead of adding my PNGs to assets I could add them to myApp.com/images and read from there, **regardless of whether it's been installed internally or to the SD card?**

Any help is appreciated

regards
~david

Comment: You can use them directly if you place them in the project's `/res/drawable` directory - or am I misunderstanding what you're asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Context.getAssets()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets() returns an `AssetManager` that allows you to read bundled data.
For example

```
InputStream is=getAssets().open("image.png",AssetManager.ACCESS_STREAMING);
```

Will read image.png from your assets folder.

Comment: ok, thanks for the tip, I was hoping that I could directly set an ImageView image from the bundle, not through an InputStream. Let me see if I can figure it out before accepting the answer (in case anyone give me the direct tip to load to the ImageView)

Comment: If you want to set it directly, add it as a resource. If it is asset, pass the input stream to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InputStream)`

Comment: BEAUTIFUL! many many thanks rkapl, I was already thinking that it was too much overload having to move all files to the assest folder (and checking at every launch if they were already moved as one does for a database) and then loading from there. THANKS again

Comment: this was all I needed (within a try / catch of course): ivSection.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.getAssets().open("images/1_ksi2.png",AssetManager.ACCESS_BUFFER)));